# Genius mathematicians who never published anything

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history, mathematicians

Amongst philosophers, [Socrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) is an example of a genius with a great influence on human history who never wrote anything. Almost all facts which are known about his revolutionary ideas are written by his students like Plato and Xenophon.

> **Question:** What are examples of genius mathematicians in modern or ancient eras whose ideas had a great influence on development of mathematics but never wrote or published anything?

Comment: *Genius Mathematicians who Never Published Anything* - Yeah, I know, I'm slow with the typing... Just have patience.

Comment: @Lucian I am waiting eagerly... :-)

Comment: Do classmates count? You know, those guys who won't do problem sets but "know their math really well".

Comment: This question would fit very well on [hsm.se]

Comment: [William James Sidis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_James_Sidis)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 This could be an answer.

Comment: I generally dislike the idea of "mathematical geniuses". Great ideas from great people come from hard work in all cases...

Comment: There won't be many (any?) proper answers to the question  as long as it asks for mathematicians who didn't publish *anything*. Notice that the answers so far only mention mathematicians who published not much (therefore my downvotes...; people should read the question before answering it).

Comment: Did Paul Erdős ever publish anything? :)

Answer (score 30):

There are influential posthumous papers by authors who did not publish them.

Galois had an immense influence on algebra because of the publication of something he wrote the night before he died in a duel.  He gave us the word "group".

Thomas Bayes had an influential posthumous paper in which he found the conditional probability distribution of a random variable $P$ whose marginal distribution is uniform on $[0,1]$, given the observation of the number of successes in $n$ trials that are conditionally independent given $P$, where the conditional probability of success on each trial, given $P$, is $P$.  He did publish things while he lived.

Mary Cartwright never published her proof of the irrationality of $\pi$.  A question she set on an examination was to fill in its details.  We know of it only because Sir Harold Jeffries included it in an appendix in one edition (and not in other editions) of one of  his books, and he leaves the impression that he knew of it only because of its occurrence on that examination.

Comment: For those who don't know, Galois was less than 21 years old when he died in that duel!

Comment: @Michael Hardy: could you indicate the gist of Dame Cartwright's proof? (Although back in graduate school I heard her lecture about her work on dynamical systems growing out of the British radio problem, I never before heard about the proof you mention.)

Comment: Here is is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Cartwright.27s_proof ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @murray : I failed to "notify" you when I posted the item above. Now you're notified.

Comment: No, Galois developed his ideas on groups years before and had written manuscipts. What he wrote the night before the duel was letters to urge other people to publish his work postumously.

Answer (score 24):

<sub>The words "never" and "anything" are somewhat restrictive (and we know that absolute statements are *always* wrong). Nowadays, you can't be recognized at all when you're not publishing. Additionally, the term "Genius" is hard to define...</sub>

---

One person came to my mind is [Grigori Yakovlevich Perelman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman). He hardly published anything, did not even defend his dissertation, and was one of the few leading researchers at his institute who only was a "PhD *candidate*". Of course, strictly speaking, he *did* publish something, particularly his proof of a generalization of the [Poincaré conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture). But this was not published in some mathematical Journal, but only on [arXiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv).

---

<sub>I think that someone who casually finds a proof for a generalization of a conjecture that dozens of mathematicians had been working on for 98 years, and doesn't give a ... care about the formal process of scientific publications qualifies as a genius, and is close enough to "never publishing anything" to be mentioned here, at least...</sub>

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your nice answer. Just a logical paradox: *"absolute statements are **always** wrong!"* is an *absolute statement* itself!

Comment: @AliSadeghDaghighi I like paradoxes (maybe I should have made clear somehow that this was intentional)

Comment: @Marco13 We got you the first time. Now its so overt. That *always* spoils the charm.

Comment: Perelman published quite a few papers in a usual way. Even before the whole story about Poincare's conjecture he was offered a number of positions in different US universities.

Comment: "Hardly published anything" is not quite right. I don't have access to MathSciNet now but on Google Scholar I found more than 10 published by Perelman (also with well known coauthors). I guess his total paper count is about 20.

Comment: @Dirk and Artem: Sure, as I tried to point out: It's hard to know someone who did not publish anything at all (not even his name - scnr). His bibliography at Wikipedia lists only a handful of other publications, but I did not do a detailed survey. One (maybe the main) reason for mentioning him was his obvious *attitude* towards the "publishing rat race" and his ingenuity - a combination that may be considered as an extreme form of "Pauca sed matura" (the motto of Gauß - who published a lot, but also left a considerable amount of his work unpublished, by the way).

Comment: Wikipedia usually lists a few and perhaps the most relevant papers and often do not even include any papers.  To get some ideas of the paper output one needs to check primary sources.  I checked MathSciNet and he has 16 entries. His (short) list of coauthors is impressive and he has published in top notch journals.

Comment: @Dirk Should I rephrase it to something like "He has comparatively few publications" or so? After all (I have to say that I'm not a mathematician and) his name was one that came to my mind, and I wanted to mention him - whether his name counts as one of the examples that the asker was looking for is hard to judge...

Answer (score 16):

Riemann published but 15 papers in his lifetime. One of my professors once told me, perhaps apocryphally, that one of those papers contained an error, and that his distress over the error led him to poor health and eventually his death.

After his death, his housekeeper "cleaned up" his papers, losing who knows how many of his mathematical ideas forever.

Comment: Are the downvotes because of the anecdote, or because 15 is too large to be in the domain of "nothing".

Comment: I'd guess for the latter.

Answer (score 11):

Pierre de Fermat-Some of his works and theorems were published by his son. His works, including Fermat's last theorem $(a^n+b^n\neq c^n \,\forall n>3,a,b,c,n\in\mathbb{Z})$ were not published until his death.

Comment: Was going to correct you and say "some." And people such as Pascal knew of his work - much of Fermat's work was communicated in private letters to other scientists.

Comment: Did Fermat have much to say about his last theorem? Other than the proof being too big to fit in the margin of his paper? ;)

Comment: In those days there was nothing resembling "publication" in the sense of the last 250+ years.

Answer (score 6):

I think Thales of Miletus is the most obvious answer, although perhaps a bit boring. From wiki:

> Thales involved himself in many activities, taking the role of an
>   innovator. Some say that he left no writings, others say that he wrote
>   On the Solstice and On the Equinox. (No writing attributed to him has
>   survived.)

He is said to have basically invented mathematics, or rather the axiomatic proof-based approach to mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

[Joshua King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_King) could be an example of a genius mathematician who never gave a lecture and  published almost no papers but one.

Comment: The linked page seems to me to suggest that he was _not_ a genius mathematician; he certainly doesn't seem to have done any mathematics after he graduated Cambridge, which I would argue disqualifies him as a mathematician no matter what his title is.

Comment: @cpast I think at that time, it was clear to people around him that he is a genius mathematician and a true substitute of Newton and this was the main reason for appointing him on such a high academic position.

Comment: Again, not how I'm reading it. The way I read it, he showed promise in examinations, but while people at the time thought he was a genius mathematician, the reputation was entirely undeserved, because for all practical purposes he was _not_ a mathematician, and he did no mathematics after being first in his class at university.

Answer (score 2):

To echo others, the question leaves a lot open to interpretation; however, my vote would have to go to Gosset, the inventor of the "t Distribution."

> William Sealy Gosset (13 June 1876 – 16 October 1937) was an English statistician. He 
>   published under the pen name Student, and developed the Student's t-distribution. (wiki)

Given that Gosset published under a pen name, it could be argued that he never "published" .

> Many people are familiar with the name "Student" but not with the name Gosset. In fact Gosset wrote under the name "Student" which explains why his name may be less well 
>   known than his important results in statistics. He invented the t-test to handle small 
>   samples for quality control in brewing. Gosset discovered the form of the t 
>   distribution by a combination of mathematical and empirical work with random numbers, an early application of the Monte-Carlo method. (http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Gosset.html)

Answer (score 0):

Pythagoras and other members of his school whose names haven't survived seem like an obvious choice (along with Thales, given in another answer). Surely they had a huge effect on mathematics, which is similar to the influence of Socrates on Philosophy, but we have very little extant writings from Pythagoreans and none from Pythagoras himself.